# Need help with uploading files using the Valums ajax upload script

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

No matter what I change in this script, when I go to upload the file, the page is looking for the action do-nothing.htm. This is what the `ACTION` of the plugin is set to in the downloaded example, but I have changed it.

I have also changed some lines in the Javascript to see if I could get something working, but nothing. In fact I can't seem to find any reference to do-nothing.htm yet the console still gives me a 404 error do-nothing.htm not found. Any ideas?

Comment: Is the downloaded code on the package working in their example?

Comment: no, in the example the action of the uploader is set to "do-nothing.htm" i have changed the action to a php script, so that the file can actually be uploaded. I thought maybe the page was being cache'd or something, i've cleared the cache, reset all of my browsers and yet the page is still looking for the page "do-nothing.htm" The example on the website is working, but not the downloaded example.

Comment: Posting on its website might be better idea

Comment: The example proviced worked for me, replace do-nothing.htm with the page which handles the file uploads

Comment: The script for handling the upload in their example is in the html header not the seperate .js file. I fell for this last night after tweeking the .js file for ages only for it to still say that it was using do-nothing.htm all the time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the example works.